# localize "N messages", Android

Tags: android, localization, internationalization

My question sounds really stupid: I want to localize the message
*"N messages"*.

The problem is that I cannot predict how the word for *message* must be inflected in different languages.

AFAIK the constructs to express *"N messages"* range from just *"N of message"* in Chinese to things like *"hundred fourteen message and three-twenty"* (that is, 174) and Russian inflection rules that even Russians themselves find too difficult to explain, the inflection depends on `(n % 10)`. (English and Polish are somewhere in the middle, they do require inflection, but the rules are simple; in some languages, there is a *dual number*, a special form for n=2.)

This must have been already solved, but don't see how.

It is tempting to write just `"%i message(s)"` and let the translator's head ache, but there's something wrong in it. (Namely, this would mean that I assume the English grammar to be universal. When people assume that the grammar or their language is universal, they ask questions like "why cannot you use Chinese hieroglyphs to write in English" and "why don't you use Latin alphabet to write in Chinese".)

I know about Android resource strings, but they do not help with inflection.

**What should I do to let my program perfectly display *"N messages"*  in any language?**

UPD: nobody replies, does that mean that there's no solution?

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly pointed out, there's really no good solution.  In the past, when working closely with localization companies, you could generally solve the problem by doing something like:

```
Number of messages: N
```

or

```
Number of message to display: N
```

Where N is the number.  While it's not ideal, it's probably the only way to deal with multiple locales and languages.